# Crash in Firefox or Chrome when using FileReader

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, crash, filereader

We try to upload a zip file using the “FileReader” javascript object on the client. For small files, everything seems to be fine. If we use a zip input file of 132Mo, in Firefox v21.0 on Windows 7, the first upload from the local disk thru the javascript object works well. But, if we try to select another file and start the transfert, Firefox crashes…. In Chrome v27.0 on Windows 7, it crashes(see the ‘oups’ page) on the first try. We tried on a Mac OS with same browsers without problem. Mainly strange but when the Windows task manager window is open, no more crash in Firefox or Chrome while loading big files. Maybe the presence of this TOP window forces the garbage collector to do its work faster?

Has anyone already faced this issue? As reference, I joined a simple HTML page that may reproduce the behavior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#btnFile").change(startUpload);
    });

    function startUpload(e)
    {
        this.fileHandle = e.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onprogress = function (data)
        {
            if (data.lengthComputable)
            {
                var progress = parseInt(((data.loaded / data.total) * 100), 10);
                $("#progress").html("Reading file: " + progress + " %");
            }
        };
        reader.onloadend = function ()
        {
            $("#progress").html("Reading completed!");
        };
        reader.onerror = function (errorEvent)
        {
            console.error("FileReader error", errorEvent);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileHandle);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="btnFile" />
    <div id="progress"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading line-by-line file in JavaScript on client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647563/reading-line-by-line-file-in-javascript-on-client-side)