# How to read online file line by line?

Tags: javascript, url, file-read

I'm sorry for this very basic question, but I can't find it out. Basically I'm trying to read [this file](https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/files/M%E1%BB%99t%20h%E1%BB%87%20th%E1%BB%91ng%20ni%E1%BB%81m%20tin/Node%20list) line-by-line, then in another HTML page whenever there is a string that match one of these lines, then it will be wrapped within the `<span class="hello">...</span>` tag. For the latter I can use the [findAndReplaceDOMText](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText) library, and I thought that the former should be easy too. But I can only find answers to read an **uploaded** file. That is, using

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

to upload it. For example: [How to use Javascript to read local text file and read line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23331546/3416774), [Reading line-by-line file in JavaScript on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24647563/3416774). Googling [`js read line by line`](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+read+line+by+line&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AOaemvKx_8AQve6Cyl9TiNPjy3nYyMbH-w%3A1641653971567&ei=06bZYc-HIpOVr7wPuNSWyAY&ved=0ahUKEwiPvcbOtaL1AhWTyosBHTiqBWkQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=js+read+line+by+line&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEJECMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIABBHELADOgQIIxAnOgQIABBDOgUIABCABDoICAAQgAQQyQNKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQc1icEmC2E2gBcAJ4AYABtwSIAf0ckgEJMi03LjMuMS4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) only returns results for Node.js

Comment: Is the page you want to run this code on within the same domain as the remote file? If not you will need to get it's contents user server side code due to CORS restrictions, or use  a third party CORS proxy service

Comment: check out [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Comment: @charlietfl yes, it's on one same domain. But is there a way to code it on local before pushing it to the host?

Comment: As mentioned above use `fetch()` then split the lines as per the node answer you have

Comment: @charlietfl if I can make the file text a json file, then would it be more efficient than using `fetch()`

Comment: Sure. Then you wouldn't need to do all the manual line splitting

Comment: @charlietfl I mean, it's just easier for js to process it, but the cors procedure is still the same, right? After all it's just a text file, and the server still need to allow the clients to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and read the response as text and iterate line by line

```
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/files/M%E1%BB%99t%20h%E1%BB%87%20th%E1%BB%91ng%20ni%E1%BB%81m%20tin/Node%20list");
  const data = await response.text();
  const lines = data.split("\n");
  console.log(lines)
})();
```