Partial read of a large user's file and chunk upload from a website to a server
I'm trying to figure out if there is a way when a user upload a large file (5+ GB) on a website to read a this file by chunks and then upload it by chunks? My main concern is that without that browsers will be putting the file chosen by the user into a buffer to be process if I'm not mistaken (and the limit is around 2 gb in most of the browsers).
If I understand correctly, then Filereader API is used to build preview of an uploaded file and it won't allow to read file from a file system part by part and iteratively upload each part.
I have the next code for a chunk upload:
const file = data.fileSrc[0];
    const chunkSize = 1024*1024;

    if (file) {
        const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size/chunkSize);

        const sendChunk = async (start, end) =>{
              const blobSlice = file.slice(start, end);
              console.log(blobSlice)

              try {
                  const response = await fetch(`URL`, {
                      method: 'POST',
                      body: blobSlice,
                      headers: {
                          'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
                      }
                  })
        
                  if (response.ok) {
                      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
                      renderResponse(jsonResponse);
                  } else {
                      console.error(response.statusText)
                  }
        
             } catch (error) {
                  console.log(error);
             }
       }

       for(let i=0; i<totalChunks; i++) {
             const start = i*chunkSize;
             const end = (i + 1) * chunkSize;
             await sendChunk(start, end);
       }

Do I understand correctly that to execute this code a browser will hold the whole file in memory? Or nowadays browsers hold only some part of the file and then load others for processing?
If browsers hold the whole file in memory then can you please help to elaborate how very large files should be handled for upload?

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191289/19801189 (though it's a quite old post)
